# looking for english of kli yakar on noach 11:1

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries, parashat-noach

I'm looking for the English of the Kli Yakar in Parshas Noach, 11:1. or even just a summary. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**My own summary**:

The generation of dispersion characterises the statement that gatherings of bad people are bad for themselves and others. They all had their own lusts and drives, and wanted to dominate each other. This led to discord and friction, and to the point that they were better off separate.

Before that they were peacefully united and indeed feared that they would spread out into smaller discrete units that would then war against each other. In an attempt to maintain homogeneity, they decided to congregate around a central tower. However, this plan was tainted with personal motivations for "making a names for themselves", i.e. self-aggrandizement. This could lead to each one wanting to rule the new empire.

Therefore, realizing that rather than preventing war, their plan of urbanisation would ironically lead to interpersonal strife, God decided to scatter them so that given their own space, they would actually foster feelings of unity and the same language of agreement.